# In Excel, without listing every date in a range, is there a formula to determine which dates in range A fall within range B?

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

I am trying to find a formula to count the number of days an employee was on leave (K1 to N1) on dates when they were scheduled to work each month per their schedule listed in C1 to D1 and C2 to D2 on a separate sheet. Note the schedules include all days (weekends and holidays) so I can't just count NETWORKDAYs. Also, there are hundreds of crews so I need to ensure the crew and month match.

Ideally the answer would be 11 in January and 21 in February (I have manually put these in for now). Any ideas?? Anything with a script or PowerQuery Editor??

I have tried Countifs; Sumproduct, etc. and nothing has worked.

I thought this formula would get me close, no such luck.

=IF(AND($G2=B:B,R$1=F:F),MAX(0,MIN(D:D,N:N)-MAX(C:C,K:K)+1))

Here is a sample of the data I'm attempting to use: [Data sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPDZL.png)

Comment: Why would `=1+D1-C1` and `=1+D2-C2` not work?

Comment: Each date within the leave ranges and schedule ranges are not listed out.

Comment: So use a lookup function to find the correct date. The problem is not calculating the difference, but finding the correct line. You need to post better samples (data as markdown table, not screenshot) and mention columns for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged as powerquery, in that case you can use the regular comparison operators.

```
let 
    date1   = #date(2020, 1, 1), 
    date2   = #date(2022, 1, 1),
    example = #date(2021, 1, 1),
    IsInRange = example >= date1 and example <= date2
in
    IsInRange
```

If you want to build a list between two ranges, you can use a trick. Using `date`s, convert to an `integer` and then use the `range operator` like `{min..max}`

```
let 
    date1   = #date(2021, 1, 1), 
    date2   = #date(2021, 2, 21),
    // this will return a list of every day in the range, including end points
    // it doesn't matter which order you pass the dates in
    GenerateAllDays = ( source as list ) as list => 
        let
            start = List.Min( source ),
            end = List.Max( source ),
            days = { Number.From(start)..Number.From(end) },
            asDates = List.Transform( days, (item) => Date.From(item) )
        in 
            asDates,
            
    fin = GenerateAllDays( { date1, date2 } )
in
    fin
```

Comment: I don't think I explained my issue correctly. I need to determine which dates in one range, are in another range. I have 1566 rows of schedule ranges, and 126 rows of leave ranges. I need to know how many days that the person in each row was on leave when they were scheduled to work. But I need the formula or query to look up the correct crew and correct range and count how many days of the leave days were scheduled days within that specific month (I have to report them out by month).